# Why does neural network not learn after been given a lot of data and epochs?

Tags: python, numpy, neural-network

I was trying to make a neural network in Python, but it isn't working. Here's my code:

```
import numpy as np
import random


##Layers
class ForwardLayer:
    def __init__(self, ins, outs):
        self.w = np.random.random((ins, outs)) * 2 - 1
        self.b = np.random.random((1, outs)) * 2 - 1
        self.cw = np.zeros((ins, outs))
        self.cb = np.zeros((1, outs))
        self.prev = np.zeros((1, outs))
        self.ins = ins
        self.outs = outs
        self.z = np.zeros((1, outs))
        self.n = 0
    def ff(self, a):
        self.prev = a
        self.z = np.dot(a, self.w) + self.b
        return self.act(self.z)
    def act(self, a):
        return 1/(1+np.exp(-a))
    def act_d(self, z):
        return self.act(z)*(1-self.act(z))
    def bp(self, error):
        zerr = error * self.act_d(self.z)
        self.cb += zerr
        self.cw += np.dot(self.prev.transpose(), zerr)
        self.n += 1
        return np.dot(zerr, self.w.transpose())
    def updates(self, lr):
        self.b -= self.cb*lr/self.n
        self.w -= self.cw*lr/self.n
        self.cw = np.zeros((self.ins, self.outs))
        self.cb = np.zeros((1, self.outs))
    def show(self):
        print(self.w)
        print(self.b)

class Flatten:
    def __init__(self):
        self.ins = None
        self.outs = 0
    def ff(self, a):
        self.ins = a.shape
        self.outs = a.size
        return a.reshape(1, self.outs)
    def bp(self, error):
        return error.reshape(self.ins)
    def updates(self, lr):
        pass
    def show(self):
        print("Flatten!")

class DumbLayer:
    def __init__(self):
        pass
    def ff(self, a):
        return a
    def bp(self, error):
        return error
    def updates(self, lr):
        pass
    def show(self):
        pass
#Network

class Network:
    def __init__(self, layers, lr):
        self.layers = layers
        self.lr = lr
    def ff(self, a):
        for l in self.layers:
            a = l.ff(a)
        return a
    def error(self, out, exp):
        return 2*(out - exp)
    def prac(self, a, exp):
        out = self.ff(a)
        err = self.error(out, exp)
        for l in self.layers[::-1]:
            err = l.bp(err)
    def update(self):
        for l in self.layers:
            l.updates(self.lr)
    def out(self):
        for l in self.layers:
            l.show()

net = Network([Flatten(), ForwardLayer(3, 2)], 1)
in1 = np.array([0.1, 0.05, 0.05])
in2 = np.array([0.8, 0.8, 0.8])
out1 = np.array([[1, 0]])
out2 = np.array([[0, 1]])


net.out()
#data
data = []
for _ in range(1000):
    x = random.random()
    y = random.random()
    z = random.random()
    if x+y+z < 1.5:
        data.append((np.array([x, y, z]), out1))
    else:
        data.append((np.array([x, y, z]), out2))


for _ in range(100):
    for i, o in data:
        net.prac(i, o)
        net.update()
print(net.ff(in1))
print(net.ff(in2))
net.out()
```

It seems to work with smaller data sets, but it still needs many epochs and lot of time.

I tried printing the network out, simplifying number of layers and adding more epochs. I expected it to learn more and give better answers. it shows something close `[[0.56, 0.37]]` when I want it to show `[[1, 0]]`
The data is triplets of numbers with a score more or less than 1.5.

I tried reducing number of layers and outputting the network. It changed, which is a good sign. When I run the program, I get values like 0.4 and 0.5. I want it to be either [1, 0] or [0, 1]. The data sets the first one if the sum of the numbers is more than 1.5 otherwise the second one turns on.

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. We do not "find the bug" for you here. Do you understand the general theory behind how the NN is supposed to work? Would you be able to explain, step by step, what should happen when the code runs? If so, then the next step is to [check what actually happens](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/), validate that against what you expect, isolate where something goes wrong, and produce a [mre] focused on that problem. Otherwise, you have a question about neural networks, not about writing code; please try [ai.se].

Answer (score 0):

The network seems to be implemented correctly, from what I've noticed the gradient is being calculated correctly.

From what I see in the code you forgot to reset self.n = 0 when you update the weights, I add this line and check the result. Therefore, the network stops training after a certain number of iterations. Since the `n` is so big that it makes the gradient disappear.

```py
def updates(self, lr):
        self.b -= self.cb*lr/self.n
        self.w -= self.cw*lr/self.n
        self.cw = np.zeros((self.ins, self.outs))
        self.cb = np.zeros((1, self.outs))
        self.n = 0 # add this line for reset
```

When add this line, results looks like this:

```
[[1.0000000e+00 4.5076392e-30]]   # For in1
[[5.15733829e-21 1.00000000e+00]] # for in2
```